# Validation error on rel value

Tags: html

Any ideas how I can fix this?

```
Line 58, Column 72: Bad value fancybox2 for attribute rel on
    element a: Keyword fancybox2 is not registered.

…er.jpg" class="grid_1" rel="fancybox2"><img src="images/werk/klein/tubeplayer.…

Syntax of link type valid for <a> and <area>:

A whitespace-separated list of link types listed as allowed
on <a> and <area> in the HTML specification or listed as an
allowed on <a> and <area> on the Microformats wiki without duplicate
keywords in the list. You can register link types on the Microformats
wiki yourself.

    <a href="images/werk/clipta.jpg" class="grid_1" rel="fancybox2">
      <img src="images/werk/klein/clipta.jpg" alt="clipta"/></a>
```

Comment: @MPD — HTML 5. Nothing else will trigger the references to the insane "Part of the spec is a wiki!" rules it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message explains it rather well. You are using an HTML5 doctype, which means that HTML5 rules are applied, and they allow a specific [list of `rel` values](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#linkTypes) but with a wiki-based extension mechanism. This means that the rules for `rel` values may change at any moment without prior or posterior notice.

What should you do? First, consider why you are using `rel="fancybox2"`. If you have sound reasons to think that some software makes some use of it, in a useful way, keep using it and ignore the error message. If not, remove the attribute.

Theoretically, you could and should register the attribute value if you think it is useful and well-documented. But this is something that should primarily be done by people who have invented the value and defined it and promote it and have some idea of how it supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

rel can only have one of the values specified in the list you see when you click on this link: [w3schools/tags/att_a_rel](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_a_rel.asp)

What dou you want to do in the first place?

Comment: Please don't recommend W3Schools as a source. Especially when the allowed values are on a wiki and they don't track in real time.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using appears to abuse the `rel` attribute to describe something that isn't a relationship between the page and the content at the other end of the link. Change it to use a more appropriate means of storing the information, perhaps a `class` or a `data-...` attribute.